# Periodically call an observable and switch to next one only when next one succeeds

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, reactivex

I need to poll endpoint every second, currently I do it with

```
Observable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, ioScheduler)
    .switchMap { return pollWithRetrofit() }
```

It works fine except the situation when the calls start taking more than 1 second to process, so the retrofit subscription is cancelled by `swithMap` before I get any response. It can happen multiple times in a row, effectively leaving the client without any response from the poll calls for long duration. In this case I would like to not cancel the retrofit call until I get a response from the next call.

I know that `switchMap` cancels the previous subscription when the base subscription produces `onNext` call, currently it happens every second by the `Observable.interval`, so my idea is to cancel previous call only when the retrofit calls it's `onNext`, i.e moving the switching one step forward the reactive chain.

How do I do that? Or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `onBackpressureDrop` and `flatMap` with maxConcurrency of 1 to make sure a longer call is still allowed to succeed:

```
Flowable.interval(0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, ioScheduler)
.onBackpressureDrop()
.flatMap(v -> pollWithRetrofit(), 1);
```

Comment: Does maxConcurrency == 1 mean that two calls will be in parallel?

Comment: Could you describe a case of two calls taking 1,4 seconds to complete, what will happen with this code?

Comment: Why and how would mean that? It will skip that second and wait for the next free second.

Comment: Oh, nice, thank you. Will the same be achieved with `.onBackpressureDrop().concatMap`?

Comment: No, concatMap will have at least 1 pending tick cached so you'd get two calls in a quick succession.

Answer (score 2):

fwiw I'm using code like following for doing something similar...am not fully convinced that this is cleanest approach either (though has been working successfully for a while now)

```
someRetrofitInterface.apiCall()
                .repeatWhen { completed -> completed.delay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS) }
                .retry(3)
```

(from https://github.com/joreilly/galway-bus-android/blob/master/base/src/main/java/com/surrus/galwaybus/domain/interactor/GetNearestBusStopsUseCase.kt)

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that it will poll again as soon as the call succeeds if it's fast?

Comment: It will poll again after the given delay.

Comment: I see, and the delay is measured from the onCompleted() call time, right?

Comment: That's correct....which, depending on your particular requirements, may or may not be suitable

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach, but unfortunately, I would prefer to have the calls more or less fired every second.